# Implementing search that pushes results to list as soon as they become available using rxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I need to implement a search on a large data set that can take some time to complete on mobile devices. So I want to display each matching result as soon as it becomes available.

I need to fetch all available data from a data store that decides whether to get them from network or from the device. This call is an `Observable`. As soon as the data from that Observable becomes available I want to loop over it, apply a search predicate and notify any Observers for any match found.

So far my idea was to use a `PublishSubject` to subscribe to and call its `onNext` function every time the search finds a new match. However I can't seem to get the desired behavior to work.

I'm using MVVM + Android Databinding and want to display every matched entry in a `RecyclerView` so for every `onNext` event that is received by the observing viewModel I have to call `notifyItemRangeInserted` on the RecyclerView's adapter.

```
class MySearch(val dataStore: MyDataStore) {

    private val searchSubject = PublishSubject.create<List<MyDto>>()

    fun findEntries(query: String): Observable<List<MyDto>> {
        return searchSubject.doOnSubscribe {
            // dataStore.fetchAll returns an Observable<List<MyDto>>
            dataStore.fetchAll.doOnNext {
                myDtos -> if (query.isNotBlank()) {
                    search(query, myDtos)
                } else {
                    searchSubject.onNext(myDtos)
                }
            }.subscribe(searchSubject)

        }
    }

    private fun(query: String, data: List<MyDto>) {
        data.forEach {
           if (it.matches(query)) {
               // in real life I cache a few results and don't send each single item
               searchSubject.onNext(listOf(it))
           }
        }
    }

    fun MyDto.matches(query: String): Boolean // stub
}
```

-

```
class MyViewModel(val mySearch: MySearch, val viewNotifications: Observer<Pair<Int, Int>>): BaseObservable() {

    var displayItems: List<MyItemViewModel> = listOf()

    fun loadData(query: String): Subscription {
        return mySearch.findEntries(query)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(this::onSearchResult)
            .doOnCompleted(viewNotifications::onCompleted)
            .doOnError(viewNotifications::onError)
            .subscribe()
    }

    private fun onSearchResult(List<MyDto> data) {
        val lastIndex = displayItems.lastIndex
        displayItems = data.map { createItem(it) }
        notifyChange()
        viewNotifications.onNext(Pair(lastIndex, data.count()))
    }

    private fun createItem(dto: MyDto): MyItemViewModel // stub
}
```

The problem I have with the above code is that with an empty query `MyViewModel::onSearchResult` is called 3 times in a row and when the query is not empty `MyViewModel::onSearchResult` isn't called at all.
I suspect the problem lies somewhere in the way I have nested the Observables in `findEntries` or that I'm subscribing wrong / getting data from a wrong thread.

Does anyone have an idea about this?